# Vertically center the th element in table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a text "2012 Year" in the table, I want to position it centered vertically. There is a collapseIcon beside the text.

The [demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/zhshqzyc/3pajE/6/)

My questions:

1) Can we position it in the center accurately? Please don't use padding-top, I doubt that it is not accurate since we don't know the hight of the cell.

2) A little off topic, there is no tbody element in the table, why the code

```
 $('table.collapsible tbody').each(function() {
```

is still working?

Thank you.

Comment: tbody is added automatically by the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `line-height: 60px` to the `.tabletitle`. The `<img>` is 60px high and the text will be displayed in the line-height 60px middle.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pajE/7/)

Answer (score 0):

this can be done with CSS property valign:middle

If you want to do it using JQuery, you can do it as follow

```
$('table.collapsible tbody tr td').each(function() {
    $(this).css('valigh','middle');
});
```

Comment: Not the spelling mistake - `valigh`

Comment: The issue is not the parameter vertical-align but the image added in the Th that makes the text move to the right no ?